# Running Gradle Tasks In Subproject

Tags: java, gradle, build, continuous-integration

I have the following project structure:

- root

  - build.gradle
  - subprojectA

    - build.gradle
  - subprojectB

    - build.gradle

Now, there is task **doIt** declared in build.gradle from both subprojectA and subprojectB.

I am running `gradle :subprojectA:doIt` and I would expect only `doIt` from subprojectA to be ran. However, both `doIt` tasks (from both subprojectA and subprojectB) are running. It behaves the same if I run `gradle :subprojectB:doIt`.

Can anyone explain how running tasks actually works? I've been playing around for a few hours already and it's driving me insane.

Comment: It depends on the actual task. Normally, tasks are unrelated and only that task would run. But if eg. the modules are java libraries and one depends on the other, then calling `gradle :mod-a:build`, and would cause the other project to be built.

Comment: and anyway tasks can be made to depend on other tasks, eg. with `module1.task1.dependsOn(module1.task2)`